# How to extract attrbute value in cypress

Tags: typescript, cypress

My HTML:

[image]

I have to extract td value which is "newone@wxample.com"

when i do :

```
 TemplatePage.getInvitaionPendingUser().each(($user, index, $list) => {
       if($user.text('Invitation pending')){
        userEmail =  $user.innerText()
       }
    });
```

it gives me div text which is "Invitaion pending"

using cypress with typescript

Comment: Please add the entire html to the question. it is very difficult to debug from the html that you posted.

Comment: Please don't use images as a code examples. In worst case, your question will be downvoted an closed

Comment: i cant copy the DOM , so pasting an image, is there a way to copy dom - sorry i have no knowledge in this, please help if there is a way

Comment: To get the HTML as text, right-click the `<table>` element and chose "Edit as HTML", then ctrl-A to select all, ctrl-c to copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
cy.contains('Invitation pending')
  .parent('td')
  .invoke('text')
  .then((text) => {
    cy.log(text) //will print newone@wxample.com and Invitation pending
  })
```

You can then use JS methods like split to extract your text newone@wxample.com. Or, you can add the log text what you are getting in the comments then I can edit the answer.

Comment: thanks , it helped

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `.contains()` on the whole `<td>`

```js
cy.contains('td', 'Invitation pending')  / checks the child div also!
  .each($user => {
    userEmail =  $user.innerText()
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for `$user.text().includes()`, depending on what element is `$user`.

```js
TemplatePage.getInvitaionPendingUser().each(($user, index, $list) => {

 if ($user.text().includes('Invitation pending') {
   userEmail =  $user.innerText()
 }
});
```